# Is there a verb for "to make audible"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for verb that fits for "make your heartbeat audible/hearable".

But not a verb that describes the action with our sense organ, like in "hear your heartbeat" or in "see your heartbeat".
More like "visualize your heartbeat", but for hearing.

Comment: Do you mean like ***amplify***?

Comment: *feel the beating of your heart*?

Comment: @Jim in this sense, but not exactly, since "amplify your heartbeat" could also be interpreted as "increase your heart rate"

Comment: @bbjay -  *amplify* has to do with amplitude not frequency.

Comment: @Jim you're right. But 'to amplify' is not specific for audio signals, as you can amplify any kind of signal, like amplify a color or light beam and the result is the same, just intensified. Whereas 'to visualize' specifically makes something invisible and not necessarily present in the form of light, perceivable for our eyes. The verb I'm looking for should be more specific to audio, making something perceptible for our ears. I think we're getting closer ;-)

Comment: From [Garner's Modern English Usage...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+no+use+for+artificialize%22)  *neologisms ending in -ize are generally to be discouraged, for they are usually ungainly and often superfluous. Thus we have no use for artificialize, **audiblize,** cubiclize,fenderize (= to fix a dented fender), funeralize, ghettoize ...* Personally, I've no problem with *visualise = form a picture of something **in one's mind***, but if OP wants it to mean *present/convert information to visual format* I think that's a bit "geeky". And the ***audio*** version is awful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that would totally make an acceptable answer. And yes, I've a tech background, hence the geekiness ;-)

Comment: 'Audibilize' is acceptable (and "-ize = to make" is not superfluous).  'Amplify' should be reserved for the sound of the heartbeat, not the heartbeat itself; and 'sonify' would make audible something that had no sound.

Comment: @AmI 'sonify' it is! I will gladly accept that as an answer if you post it as one.

Comment: No - I didn't like it because a heartbeat is already audible under the right conditions.  Sonification requires a transduction (change of form), such as a VU meter *visualizes* sound, or a Theremin *sonifies* gestures.  'Audibilize' is a more general word, since it includes sound amplification as well.

Comment: bbjay: There are lots of webpages where you can listen to the "sound" of recently-detected gravity waves, but I kinda doubt many of them would resort to nonce-words like ***audibilize, audify, sonicalize, sonify, soundify.*** The bottom line is English doesn't (yet?) have an acceptable widely-recognised single-word term for the action. You really need to stick to extended forms such as ***render / convert to audio format*** if you don't want to exaggerate said "geekiness".

Comment: I'm thinking there was another nearly identical question about a month ago.

Comment: *Assisted listening* is pretty close and well established in the hearing loss field. The ADA uses the term generically in the form of *assisted listening devices*. Assisted listening can be dead simple such as a receiving horn, or it can mean miking, processing, transmitting, decoding, amplifing and replaying the audio.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a specific word that would be well-understood to mean what you want.  I think what you would use to get the idea across would have to be something approximate, being either slightly off or slightly too broad.

I personally would choose "amplify", given the context you suggest:

- *I am using this stethoscope to **amplify** your heartbeat.*

This isn't quite what you're asking for, but a typical english language speaker would definitely infer "listen intently, at an enhanced volume" from "amplify".

Other options just seem too far from what you're asking.  The most direct verb is just "hear", and clearly that isn't what you're looking for.  The closest thing to "visualize" would be "hear in my head" and that's not even remotely what you want.

There may be some esoteric word that does mean exactly what you want, but I suspect it's not well-known and thus may not really be the best choice, unless this is meant for a very specific audience that is aware of its meaning.

Comment: +1 Lots of things can be amplified, and sound is one of them.   "Amplify the sound" is the simple, instantly understandable phrase.  As for visualizing the heartbeat, which the OP uses as an analogy, that can be done on an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

According to the OED "louden" means "Make or become louder."
So, according to the OED, you would "louden your heartbeat" eg. using an amplifier!

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/louden

I have to admit however, "louden" sounds a bit unwieldy! You could, as suggested by @jim "amplify" or if it doesn't need to be a single word "audibly amplify" or "render audible" as @FumbleFingers suggests.

Id just add that the OED definition of "amplify" is "Increase the volume of (sound), especially using an amplifier."

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/amplify

Sadly I don't think "Audibilize" or "sonify" are currently in the OED - however, maybe it's time they were!

Comment: You linked to ODO (Oxford Online Dictionary), not OED. The OED, found at OED.com, has different definitions for *louden* or *amplify*.

Comment: Thanks Lauren! I stand corrected. So, does the definition for "louden" in the OED still work? It is much the same in most of the online dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the verb ***to sound***. Below are the definitions that might pertain to your word usage choice, from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound):

> ***sound***
> *verb*
>
> **transitive verb**
> 1a : to cause to sound 
> *sound a trumpet*
>
> 3a: to make known
> b: to order, signal, or indicate by a sound
> *sound the alarm*
>
> **intransitive verb**
> 1a : to make a sound
> c: to give a summons by sound
> *the bugle sounds to battle*

In your case, the phrase could then be formed like ***sound your heartbeat*** or the like, to mean to ***make your heartbeat audible***. It's sort of like saying *sound the drums* to mean *strike the drums to make a sound* as well.

Answer (score 0):

The auditory analogy with ‘visual’ is ... ‘auditory’.  So that the verb that corresponds to ‘visualise’, if it existed, would be ...’auditoryise’.?  ... ‘auditorialise’?  Well, no wonder nobody has ever coined it:  it would be a real clunker.  I would stick to your idea of imagining the sound of your heart beating.  It is quite clear.

Comment: The OED also attests as adjectives beginning with *audi-* all of *audible, audient, audile, auditive, auditorial, auditory,* and *auditual*. You'll have to check for yourself whether any apply.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, in a way. However, don’t we have to balance the relative merits of finding a single but unfamiliar word or coinage, which most readers will have to look up or at least look up, against the clarity of a simple phrase or clause?  Possibly a poet might, though in the list you have shown I do not see any word a poet would jump to. Perhaps, if imagining sounds in your head became an essential part of musical composition, we might have such a word.  But I know of no composer or jazz soloist who has found such a word necessary in explaining his/her art.  But nothing doing here either.